# Automatically add elipses if text overflows in an HTML5 Windows 8 app

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I always have a hard time searching for anything about Windows 8 development, so sorry if this is simple and out there somewhere...

Is there any way to automatically put an ellipses (...) at the end of a heading/paragraph/etc if the content is overflowing in a Windows 8 HTML5 app? I know Mozilla supports `text-overflow: ellipses;`, but that doesn't work with this, nor does `-ms-text-overflow: ellipses;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to that article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh996980.aspx this should work:

```
-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Make sure about the spelling: ellipsis, not ellipses.

Comment: Not this only works for single line; you can't wrap and ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to find the status of a given feature is to check it on caniuse.com. If a given feature is supported for IE10, you should be able to use it in an HTML/JS app for the Windows Store. The caniuse.com search is very robust, like so:

http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow

and there are links to resources such as http://www.css3files.com/text/ for additional info and proper syntax.

As for wrap and text-overflow: ellipsis together, apparently that's not possible with pure CSS, but there are a few workarounds folks have recommended here on SO that might be worth trying:

[Anybody know a way to use CSS text-overflow on text that's wrapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390086/anybody-know-a-way-to-use-css-text-overflow-on-text-thats-wrapping)

For more info on developing Windows Store apps, check out [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).